# Regex for finding date in Apache access log

Tags: python, regex

I'm writing a python script to extract data out of our 2GB Apache access log.  Here's one line from the log.

```
81.52.143.15 - - [01/Apr/2008:00:07:20 -0600] "GET /robots.txt HTTP/1.1" 200 29 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; fr; rv:1.8.1) VoilaBot BETA 1.2 (http://www.voila.com/)"
```

I'm trying to get the date portion from that line, and regex is failing me, and I'm not sure why.  Here's my python code:

```
l = 81.52.143.15 - - [01/Apr/2008:00:07:20 -0600] "GET /robots.txt HTTP/1.1" 200 29 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; fr; rv:1.8.1) VoilaBot BETA 1.2 (http://www.voila.com/)"

re.match(r"\d{2}/\w{3}/\d{4}", l)
```

returns nothing.  Neither do the following:

```
re.match(r"\d{2}/", l)
re.match(r"\w{3}", l)
```

or anything else I can thing of to even get *part* of the date.  What am I misunderstanding?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

match() looks for a match at the beginning of the string. Use search() to look for a match anywhere in the string. More info here: http://docs.python.org/library/re.html#matching-vs-searching

Comment: How did I miss that.  Thanks for the quick reply.

Answer (score 1):

Or you can use one of already available python apache log parsers like :

- Apachelogs
- Logtools
- Logrep (Wtop package)

Answer (score 0):

`match()` tries to match the entire string. Try [`search()`](http://docs.python.org/library/re.html#re.search) instead.

See also the [Python Regular Expression HOWTO](http://docs.python.org/howto/regex.html), and the [Python page](http://www.regular-expressions.info/python.html) at the always-excellent [regular-expressions.info](http://www.regular-expressions.info/).

Answer (score 0):

Rather than using regular expressions to get the date, it might be easier to just split the line on spaces and extract the date:

```
 l = '81.52.143.15 - - [01/Apr/2008:00:07:20 -0600] "GET /robots.txt HTTP/1.1" 200 29 "-" Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; fr; rv:1.8.1) VoilaBot BETA 1.2 (http://www.voila.com/)"'
 date = l.split()[3]
```

If you're processing very large files, this is probably more efficient than using regular expressions.

Comment: I thought about that too, but I also want grab the user-agent string, and splitting on spaces wrecks that.  
Also, personally `re.search('\d{2}/\w{3}/\d{4}` seems more semantic (find two digits/three characters/four digits) than `l.split()[3]` (find the fourth chunk in the string).  For future readability.